# Kubuntu install hangs on Connex LiteBook

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu, uefi, freeze

I have a Connex LiteBook that won't load into Windows so I don't  want to fix that and want to replace it with Ubuntu. Seeing as the LiteBook is pretty weak hardware wise I want to install Kubuntu.

I downloaded the Kubuntu ISO, checked SHA256 hash and then used Startup Disk Creator to make a bootable USB stick.

Went to Laptop, started it, went into BIOS and booted from USB. I see the Grub menu and select Kubuntu...

nothing.

So I checked around a bit on the web. Changed a bunch of settings in BIOS and tried again.

nothing

Reset BIOS to defaults and tried adding "acpi=off" to the boot command and it gave me the furthest I got with it thus far... however it freezes at the following

[ 1.188980] Freeing unused kernel image (initmem) memory: 2684K

So I'm stumped as to what to do next. The system uses UEFI I should also just add.
Anyone know what I could try next?

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: Did it ever run Windows? If so why did it stop working? You may have a hardware problem.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi - The specs say 3GB of Ram

|   David - It used to run Windows but after some time I wanted to do a reset to fresh install. Shift+Restart gave me the "safemode" options but just wouldn't boot after refresh. Automatic Repair Mode also just loads and loads.

Comment: Please [format your question](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) with enough [details](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) so that one can find an adequate answer.